# When does Safari Technology Preview get into production?

Tags: safari

Understand that the latest as of this question is Release 18 from https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/release-notes/

I can't find any place where they mention when it is coming to production. Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not comment on the timing or contents of future releases.

That said, Safari Technology Preview tracks WebKit and Safari trunk. So I think the answer is "eventually".